# how to convert XML strings to JSON

Tags: xml, json, web-services

I see a bunch posting on this topic, but they are all very dated.

So I have a WSDL file with a large number of complex types such as:

```
<complexType name="RM-CTRL-INFO-S">
<!--  RM_CTRL_INFO_S  -->
<sequence>
<element name="ctrl-type" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<!--  RM_CTRL_INFO_S::ctrl_type  -->
<element name="fw-ver" type="ns:Array60Ofbyte" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true"/>
<!--  RM_CTRL_INFO_S::fw_ver  -->
<element name="ram-size" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<!--  RM_CTRL_INFO_S::ram_size  -->
<element name="status" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<!--  RM_CTRL_INFO_S::status  -->
<element name="bg-task-rate" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<!--  RM_CTRL_INFO_S::bg_task_rate  -->
<element name="valid-cache-modes" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<!--  RM_CTRL_INFO_S::valid_cache_modes  -->
<element name="autoclear-mode" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<!--  RM_CTRL_INFO_S::autoclear_mode  -->
<element name="tot-disks" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<!--  RM_CTRL_INFO_S::tot_disks  -->
<element name="tot-raids" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<!--  RM_CTRL_INFO_S::tot_raids  -->
<element name="tot-vols" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<!--  RM_CTRL_INFO_S::tot_vols  -->
<element name="stripe-size" type="ns:Struct-1" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<!--  RM_CTRL_INFO_S::stripe_size  -->
<element name="single-bit-ecc-err" type="xsd:unsignedInt" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<!--  RM_CTRL_INFO_S::single_bit_ecc_err  -->
<element name="multi-bit-ecc-err" type="xsd:unsignedInt" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<!--  RM_CTRL_INFO_S::multi_bit_ecc_err  -->
<element name="patrol-start-err" type="xsd:unsignedInt" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<!--  RM_CTRL_INFO_S::patrol_start_err  -->
<element name="max-devices" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<!--  RM_CTRL_INFO_S::max_devices  -->
</sequence>
</complexType>
```

What is the good way to generate JSONs from these?

Comment: Convert to a "nest" of Maps and Lists and then serialize that into JSON.

Comment: looking for a tool such as wsdl2js or some similar tool XML to JSON

Comment: The difference between the tool and DIY should be trivial if the XML is well-behaved (and if your environment has an XML to Map/List converter).  The above would be roughly `[{"name":"ctrl-type", "type":"xsd:int", "minOccurs":"1" "maxOccurs":"1"}, {"name":"fw-ver", ...]`.  There should be an existing tool that converts the XML to an array of maps, and then to JSON is a single call.